# Publish a message from container to kafka running outside container

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a docker container image which produces some messages to topic of kafka which is running outside container in the same node/machine.

When i run the docker container to publish some messages to topic of kafka getting below error.

> [root@lm--mro-cloudnative--central docker_producer]# docker run
> test-producer %3|1544419029.623|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1|
> [thrd:lm--mro-cloudnative--central.novalocal:9092/0]:
> lm--mro-cloudnative--central.novalocal:9092/0: **Failed to resolve
> 'lm-cloudnative--central.novalocal:9092': Name or service not
> known (after 342076146ms in state INIT)**
>
> %3|1544419029.623|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1|
> [thrd:lm--mro-cloudnative--central.novalocal:9092/0]:
> lm--cloudnative--central.novalocal:9092/0: **Failed to resolve
> 'lm-cloudnative--central.novalocal:9092': Name or service not
> known (after 342076146ms in state INIT)**

My producer python code as below,(**producer.py**)

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import json

data = {"name":"LTE", "parameters":{"Period":1},"targets":[88054]}

conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
        'default.topic.config': {'produce.offset.report': True, 'request.required.acks' : -1}}
p = Producer(**conf)

json_data = json.dumps(data)
p.produce('mro_topic', key='MRO', value=json_data, callback=None)
p.flush(30)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM registry-access-redhat-com.repo.lab.pl.**-**.com/rhel7.4

# CONFIGURE YUM
RUN rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/*
ADD resources/yum.repos.d/* /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN echo "sslverify=false" >> /etc/yum.conf


RUN yum install -y python-pip
RUN pip install --index-url https://repo.lab.pl.**.com/api/pypi/python/simple/ pip
RUN pip install --index-url https://repo.lab.pl.**.com/api/pypi/python/simple/ requests
RUN pip --version
RUN pip install --index-url https://repo.lab.pl.**.com/api/pypi/python/simple/ setuptools

RUN pip install --index-url https://repo.lab.pl.**.com/api/pypi/python/simple/ confluent-kafka
RUN pip install --index-url https://repo.lab.pl.**.com/api/pypi/python/simple/ avro
ADD producer.py /
CMD [ "python", "producer.py" ]
```

**docker build -t test-producer .**

**docker run test-producer**

Is there anyting i missed ?

Comment: Suggestion: Use `os.environ` in the Python code to dynamically change Kafka location at runtime

Answer (score 2):

With host as "localhost:9092" it won't work because it points to the same docker container not to the node/machine.

Solution:
Instead of localhost use IP address of node/machine then it should work.

Comment: Thanks.Its working now. Use of IP address alone did not solve the problem. In the kafka `server.properties` the following property has to be enabled and restart the kafka. `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<IP>:9092`